# form submit only giving last value in a loop codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

Here is my view

```
 <?php for($i=0;$i<count($acb['def']);$i++) { ?>
<input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $abc['def'][$i]?>" />?>
```

Here is my controller

```
 $xxx=$this->input->post('xyz')
```

Now when i submit the form the last value only gets posted to controller

then i found that the name is same for all fields so it takes last value , so i changed the  input name as

```
name ='xyz[$i]'
```

Now i need to post values , How to post values with this

Comment: Use `name="xyz[]"`

Comment: if you print $xxx what does it say after you put name = 'xyz[i]'  ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send name as array rename it to 'xyz[]' here

```
<input type="text" name="xyz[]" value="<?php echo $abc['def'][$i]?>" />?>
```

Comment: how to get the value controller?

Comment: `$this->input->post('xyz')` will be an array

Comment: i dont want as a array i need as value so how to get

Comment: implode in a variable at the last : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Comment: here all  values are passed in array but i want to post only the selected field rather than passing all values

Comment: what type of selection, I don't understand, ?

Comment: say for ex in a loop three times the input box and submit box comes , i am clicking 2nd submit button since i have selected 2nd submit button only the value of 2nd input box should be posted rather than all fields as a array

Comment: yes it will send all three inputbox values, it not right ?

Answer (score 0):

You use to below code...

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($acb['def']);$i++) { ?>
  <input type="text" name="xyz[]" value="<?php echo $abc['def'][$i]?>" />
?>
```

Comment: while posting  all  values are passed in array but i want to post only the selected field rather than passing all values.. How to do it